# Android Unit test does not work

Tags: android, unit-testing

Hei,

I am new to Android testing. I try to write the test for multiplying two numbers using editText. It seems not run and displays nothing on emulator. My test code is as follows

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.example.calculator.MainActivity;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class MathValidation extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private Solo solo;
    public MathValidation() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo=new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
    public void Test() throws Exception{
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("wrong activity", MainActivity.class);
        solo.enterText(0, String.valueOf("10"));
            solo.enterText(1,String.valueOf("30"));
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("300"));


    }
```

and here is my logcat

```
01-15 16:23:27.832: E/Trace(1190): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-15 16:23:27.832: W/Trace(1190): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:27.832: W/Trace(1190): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:27.832: W/Trace(1190): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:28.322: D/dalvikvm(1190): GC_CONCURRENT freed 331K, 15% free 2565K/3012K, paused 72ms+101ms, total 265ms
01-15 16:23:28.322: D/dalvikvm(1190): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
01-15 16:23:28.713: D/dalvikvm(1190): GC_CONCURRENT freed 484K, 20% free 2540K/3144K, paused 73ms+85ms, total 215ms
01-15 16:23:28.862: W/Trace(1190): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:28.862: W/dalvikvm(1190): method Landroid/test/InstrumentationTestRunner$StringResultPrinter;.print incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Ljunit/textui/ResultPrinter;
01-15 16:23:31.202: E/Trace(1216): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-15 16:23:31.212: W/Trace(1216): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:31.212: W/Trace(1216): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:31.212: W/Trace(1216): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:31.772: D/dalvikvm(1216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 334K, 16% free 2558K/3012K, paused 72ms+85ms, total 246ms
01-15 16:23:32.182: D/dalvikvm(1216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 491K, 18% free 2571K/3124K, paused 72ms+73ms, total 220ms
01-15 16:23:32.332: W/Trace(1216): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-15 16:23:32.332: W/dalvikvm(1216): method Landroid/test/InstrumentationTestRunner$StringResultPrinter;.print incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Ljunit/textui/ResultPrinter;
```

Answer (score 0):

All this shows is the code, not the way you're actually running the test. Are you running it from Eclipse or from the command line? Regardless, it would help to see the exact steps you're following.

Also, is Solo an Activity?

Comment: Solo is the helper used when running Robotium automated tests.

Answer (score 0):

In most test frameworks, test methods must have names that start with `test`.  The method names are case sensitive, so the problem is that your method is called `Test()` instead of `test()`.  That's why it isn't running.

Standard coding conventions in Java use method names that begin with a lower case letter.  Also, you would usually want to give more descriptive names for your tests, e.g. `testMultiply()`.